# Blogger/Blogspot redirect to own domain?

Tags: redirect, blogger, blogspot

How can I create a 301-Google friendly redirect to redirect visitors from a Blogger/Blogspot website to my own domain?

The visitors of the posts of the old domain:

```
http://example.blogspot.com/2014/03/blogpost-title.html
```

should be redirected to the new domain:

```
http://example.com/blogpost-title/
```

How do I do that with Blogger/Blogspot?

**Edit:** In the new domain I don't want to use blogspot - I use my own hosted WordPress instead.

Answer (score 5):

In blogger dashboard's setting tab there is option for publishing where you can add your custom domains. [Here is the nice post from google](https://support.google.com/blogger/troubleshooter/1233381?hl=en#ts=1734115)

Ajedi32 commented:

> Just adding your target domain as a "custom domain" will set up the redirect, even if that domain doesn't point back to Blogger as the help page presumes it will.

Comment: But i dont want to use blogspot on my custom domain - i will use wordpress instead.

Comment: @Torben I think just adding your target domain as a "custom domain" will set up the redirect, even if that domain doesn't point back to Blogger as the help page presumes it will.

Comment: @Ajedi32 it shows a warning if the domain is not served by blogger

Comment: @digitalPBK:  But it's just a warning right? So it still works?

Comment: @OskarSkog Yes if the end user clicks a link. It will not be a 301 redirect.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your blogger blog,than setting option,than basic.

there is a oprion below your blogspot url ,setting a third party domain,add your domain name there.

now go to domain name control panel,**change nameserver** as per instruction.
also add cname .
now go back to blogspot blog and click on set up a third party url,click on redirect domain.
that's all.

it may sometime tooks 24 hours if you are using godaddy or namepro domain.

Answer (score 1):

The option that i want to suggest you is redirect your blogspot visitors to home page of your own blog.

**Step-1**

Go to blogger and login with login credentials.

**Step-2**

Click on “Template” from left side menu.

**Step-3**

Here you can see blog preview. Click on “Edit HTML”. In blog html paste below code in `<head>` tag and click on “Save template”.

Let have a look at below code.

```
<meta content='2;url=http://yourdomain.com/' http-equiv='refresh'/>
```

**Read more:** [How to redirect blog from blogspot to .com](http://sgeek.org/redirect-blog-blogspot-com/)

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. All that you would need to do is + "Set up a third-party URL for your blog". it is a link in the settings section of the blog. for detailed description follow my blog.

http://www.lazygeeks.in/2015/01/forward-my-domain-to-my-blog.html

Comment: link is broken, can you update please?